# WP customizer + gulp + browsersync = refused to display in iframe?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm using gulp & browserSync for server in WP development:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: projectURL
    });
});
```

WordPress runs on `localhost:3000/mysite`

There is also a watch task that detects changes in php and reloads browser.

For some reason though WP customizer doesn't load site in iframe with the following error:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:3000/mysite/2012/01/07/template-sticky/?customize_changese…10a90359901&customize_theme=mysite&customize_messenger_channel=preview-0' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors http://localhost".
```

It works fine `http://localhost/mysite` without the port though, but won't reload automatically.

Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Comment: Did you set the port in WP config? If not, can you change it to 80?

Comment: @kero do you mean MySQL host?

Comment: Have you tried changing your site URL and home URL in WP Admin to be `http://localhost:3000`? It appears it is currently set to just `http://localhost`.

Comment: @WestonRuter yes, it's //localhost:3000 there

Comment: You can see where that header gets set here: https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/4.8.0/src/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-manager.php#L1629

I don't see how it would be stripping the port, but that's where I'd look when debugging.

Comment: @WestonRuter the link you provided lighted a lamp on my head and I found the below solution.

Comment: BrowserSync rewrites the url *in the page* to have `:3000` so it looks like it's there, but if you really change it in the database, the customizer will be rewritten to `:3000:3000` and still not work, apparently...

Answer (score 3):

Found a work around by adding ' localhost:3000' to the 'Content-Security-Policy' header:

```
function edit_customizer_headers () {
  function edit_csp_header ($headers) {
    $headers['Content-Security-Policy'] .= ' localhost:3000';
    return $headers;
  }
  add_filter('wp_headers', 'edit_csp_header');
}
add_action('customize_preview_init', 'edit_customizer_headers');
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it may be late, but I recently have found a solution with a filter:

```
function theme_set_url_scheme($url, $path, $blog_id){
    if(isset($_GET["wp_port"])){
      $parsed_url = parse_url($url);
      $parsed_url["port"] = intval($_GET['wp_port']);
      $scheme   = isset($parsed_url['scheme']) ? $parsed_url['scheme'] . '://' : '';
      $host     = isset($parsed_url['host']) ? $parsed_url['host'] : '';
      $port     = isset($parsed_url['port']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['port'] : '';
      $user     = isset($parsed_url['user']) ? $parsed_url['user'] : '';
      $pass     = isset($parsed_url['pass']) ? ':' . $parsed_url['pass']  : '';
      $pass     = ($user || $pass) ? "$pass@" : '';
      $path     = isset($parsed_url['path']) ? $parsed_url['path'] : '';
      $query    = isset($parsed_url['query']) ? '?' . $parsed_url['query'] : '';
      $fragment = isset($parsed_url['fragment']) ? '#' . $parsed_url['fragment'] : '';
      $url = "$scheme$user$pass$host$port$path$query$fragment";
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter("admin_url", "theme_set_url_scheme', null, 3);
```

And then open up the customizer with adding this querystring variable to the end:

```
&wp_port=3000
```

I tried to do this without adding the querystring parameter, but I guess browsersync redirects the calls back to server port 80, so the 3000 custom port is only visible through browser and browsersync.

---

Better option:

Add the querystring parameter to browsersync setup like this:

```
options: {
    proxy: 'wordpress.dev?wp_port=3000',
}
```

So you don't need to do anything manually. It works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to alter your gulp script in some variation of the tip on this bug report https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/1241

Hacking the source php files you are working on to get this working seems ... less good.